# Window Error :[Error123] while accessing a window directory

Tags: python, listdir

I'm using the following script

```
import os,sys
folder ='C:\Users\sohan.l\Desktop\New folder (3)\fwdfslabprograms'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
   infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
```

But it throws the following error, how can I correct it? Error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:C:\\Users\\sohan.l\\Desktop\\New folder (3)\x0cwdfslabprograms/*.*
```

Comment: Use \\ since \ is escape char.
`'C:\\Users\\sohan.l\\Desktop\\New folder (3)\\fwdfslabprograms'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a raw string in your script

```
folder = r'C:\Users\sohan.l\Desktop\New folder (3)\fwdfslabprograms'
```

As it currently stands, the `\f` is being read as a unicode character, which gets translated into a `\x0c` character.

Since the folder name becomes wrong, the particular folder is obviously not found and a `WindowsError` is thrown.